# Android Studio AVD keeps restarting

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

What does it mean when the android studio virtual device keeps restarting after the Google load screen?

I am using Pixel 5 with API level 30

Comment: have you tried to remove that AVD and re-create a new one

Comment: How about doing cold boot??

Comment: I tried that but now it's very slow

Answer (score 0):

For resolving the above question you have to follow below points:

1.Go to AVD Manager

2.Click on Right last down arrow.

3.Click on show disk

4.Go to file Location eg:(`C:\Users\msi\.android\avd\Pixel_4_XL_API_30.avd`)

5.Now Delete `.lock` file if exist.

6.Come back to AVD Manager and click down arrow.

7.Click on Wipe Data and then after competing this Click on Cold Boot Now.

Comment: Let me try this